# abbreviated references

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm trying to get the reference list be the smallest possible as I need the space, but when I try:

```
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
```

I still get a list of references that doesn't look abbreviated at all. I was wondering if there's a preset different than `abbrv` that can accomplish what I want, or if I have to make my own? I would like to see, for example, the journal names abbreviated.

Comment: The `abbrv` style (and others like it) only abbreviate author names. As far as I know there is no way (not even in BibLaTeX) to abbreviate journal names on the fly. Rather, you must provide the abbreviated journal name in your bib-file. Some bib-reference managers, like for instance JabRef, allow you to provide a database with relations-tables between full and abbreviated journal names, so that you can abbreviate (and un-abbreviate) all entries in your whole database with one click.

Comment: although there's nothing automatic about it, there are two lists of journal names with the abbreviations used by math reviews, [Abbreviations of Names of Serials](http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/serials.pdf) (pdf format) and [MR Serials Abbreviations List](http://www.ams.org/msnhtml/annser.csv) (an ascii list, in csv format, no diacritics), that can be used for reference.